# Upload files for CMS download page

Tags: cms, download

I am looking for a FTP avoiding solution to easily upload a file (like a PDF) to a CMS page.

I did find a [module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cms-downloads.html) for this but $48 for such an easy task is quite a lot.

Isn't there a better way?

Basically you only need to add a [uplodify](http://www.uploadify.com/) button and past the link into the CMS editor. Maybe someone has extended the editor before and can give me a hint how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the following XML to a module's `config.xml` allowing files with the pdf extension to be uploaded through the picture upload.

```
<adminhtml>
    <cms>
        <browser>
            <extensions>
                <allowed>
                    <pdf>1</pdf>
                </allowed>
                <image_allowed>
                    <pdf>1</pdf>
                </image_allowed>
            </extensions>
        </browser>
    </cms>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: osam @alex I Learn some thing new Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mention in your question you just only want PDF Then you can upload do one thing.

1) Upload on Images on cloud or Google Drive or Drop Box or any other free upload service provider.

2) Just take the link of that url in and In cms page using `<a>` Tag.

3) This is an example.

```
<a href="http://gradcollege.okstate.edu/sites/default/files/PDF_linking.pdf" target="_blank">test</a>
```

4) Save your Page and run your CMS page.

Comment: True, that would work but that is not something you can do for a professional shop. Uploading it somewhere else because Magento does not have a upload button feels kind of wrong.

Comment: or you can develop one extension separately and display front end side.

Comment: @user2434 in future if there is requirement then I will used this